# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) not sure why

Tags: php

i got the error for line while($array[] = $query->fetch_object());

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection to database failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "";
$query = mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM 'Contracts'");
while($array[] = $query->fetch_object());
array_pop($array);
print_r_html($array);

?>
```

I am not able to understand why??? please help! thank you

Comment: there are 2 errors here, not just one.

Comment: 'Contracts' to ` Contracts ` or Contracts

Comment: @Ash you're welcome. edit; you deleted your comment.

Comment: oops sry! that was great help! thanks :)

Comment: @Ash No worries, *cheers*

Comment: what is the best way to populate a dropdown list with data from mysql?

Comment: @Ash that would be another question. but see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471268/dropdown-list-from-mysql-column-using-mysqli and further the research using "populate dropdown select using mysqli" as keywords in Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 errors here.

First for `mysqli`. It is being treated as a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

```
$query = mysqli->query
```

it should read as

```
$query = $conn->query
```

and using `$conn` as your variable.

Then you're using single quotes around your table rather than ticks or none at all.

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Contracts`");
```

or

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Contracts");
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php